# Vstest task in Azure DevOps detecting non impacted test cases.?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, nunit, vstest, impact-analysis

We are planning to use the vstest task in our pipeline to only execute impact based nunit test.

we found that when we made a change in addition.cs file , the respective test cases are detected but along with that some other non impact test cases are also getting detected and getting executed.

our intention is that only impacted test cases should get detected  and get executed .

Did any face such scenario.? and how to fix it ,

not enough documentation available regarding the task.

Note: this are not data driven tests

to narrow down the issue we made a change only in file addition.cs ,and have created a pull request ,

currently what is happening , it detected the impacted test cases and also listed non impacted test cases ,

Expectation is that only impacted test case should be detected and executed

Need suggestion , is their any additional setting to be configured such that it only detects the impact test cases